# Trying to retrieve an arraylist in a session variable

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

So Im trying to store an a arraylist in a session variable and also be able to retrieve it.It is for a cart on a website.The problem is retrieving it.
Here is what I have so far in the servlet

```
      HttpSession session = request.getSession();
       ArrayList<Dvd> dvds;
        dvds = new ArrayList<Dvd>()= session.getAttribute("ProductsInCart");
```

The compiler error is unexpected type:required variable,found value

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
dvds = (ArrayList<Dvd>)session.getAttribute("ProductsInCart");
```

Answer (score 3):

First you did not wrote a real java statement, you need one expression on the right side of an assignment and one ore more assignees on the left. You have two expressions, what to be used?

I think you want the following two parts:

Set the attribute:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("ProductsInCart", new ArrayList<Dvd>());
```

Read the attribute:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
List<Dvd> dvds = (List<Dvd>)session.getAttribute("ProductsInCart");
```